# Vector spherical harmonics derivatives in spherical coordinates

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, electromagnetism

I am interested in taking the derivative of vector spherical harmonics in the spherical coordinate basis and I was wondering whether anyone had any good resources where to look for help in manipulating things analytically. For example,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(1)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{l(l+1)}} \nabla\times(\mathbf{r}Y_{lm}(\hat{\mathbf{r}})) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{l(l+1)}}\nabla Y_{lm}(\hat{\mathbf{r}})\times \mathbf{r} \\
    \mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(2)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{l(l+1)}}r\nabla Y_{lm}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) \\
    \mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(3)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= \hat{\mathbf{r}} Y_{lm}(\hat{\mathbf{r}})
\end{align}
$$

and I, in particular, am interested in the $\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$ derivatives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} \mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(1)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= ? \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} \mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(2)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= ? \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} \mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(3)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) &= im\mathbf{A}_{lm}^{(3)}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) + \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}Y_{lm}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}) + \dots
\end{align}
$$

Do the terms that give $\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$ from the product-rule when differentiating have a simple analytical expression in terms of the vector spherical harmonics? Any textbook or journal article resources on these derivatives as functions of $r, \theta, \phi?$

Up to some constant factors, I guess the question is whether there the action of the "angular momentum" operator $L_{z}$ on the vector spherical harmonics has a nice analytic form. If so, what are they?

---

Notations vary. If one looks at Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics, then what I am interested in is the azimuthal derivatives of $\mathbf{Y}_{lm}, \boldsymbol{\Psi}_{lm}, \boldsymbol{\Phi}_{lm}$ in the Wikipedia notation.

Comment: I am not familiar with these notations, however I know that the vector spherical harmonics have very simple expression with respect to $\varphi$, something like 
$\mathbf A_{lm} (r,\theta,\varphi)=\mathbf{B}_{lm}(r,\theta)e^{im\varphi}$ (where $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are vector valued functions).

Comment: Do you remember where you saw such expressions?

Comment: Of course, you can find them in "Spherical Near-field Antenna Measurements" by Hansen, section A1.3. The author rather call them "Spherical wave functions" and they are probably normalized differently then what you are used to.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose for the derivative with respect to $\phi$, this can be consider as the z-component of angular momentum $L_{z}$ acting on the vector spherical harmonics (up to some constant factors). Maybe I should try to look up whether those expressions are well known and documented.

Comment: Also, the equation $\mathbf{A}_{lm}(r,\theta,\phi) = \mathbf{B}_{km}(r,\theta)e^{im\phi}$ looks odd to me. In particular because I think the unit vectors $\mathbf{e}_{r}, \mathbf{e}_{\theta}, \mathbf{e}_{\phi}$ depend on $\phi,$ so I think taking the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$ will require a product rule, and that is the part that makes things messy and I am wondering if it is as messy as I think or if it has workable closed analytical expressions.

Comment: You are right, this expression is true in the spherical basis, so when you take the derivative you have to make it for the basis vector as well. But I have never written that taking the derivative with respect to $\phi$ will produce something like $(im) \mathbf{A}$, it is indeed a little more complicated. ;) Vector spherical harmonics are usually written and studied in the spherical basis so I ommited this precision sorry.

Comment: Also, you can have a look at the first vector spherical harmonics given in the wikipedia page you have linked in your question to see that this expression holds (at least for $m \le 2$, but I assure you it remains true after this).